# GetEditMenu() returns NULL

Tags: menu, wxwidgets

I have a wxCommandProcess cmd. I have code as following

```
wxCommandProcess cmd;
cmd.Submit(command);
cmd.GetEditMenu();       //NULL
```

I want to make an action history for the software. I can get the name of the command by calling GetCurrentCommand()->GetName(). It works perfect. Why is the menu is NULL? Didn't I store the command to the menu when I call submit()?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something very wrong with your understanding of `wxCommand` and `wxCommandProcessor` classes as the question just doesn't make any sense as stated. You can associate a menu with `wxCommandProcessor` just to simplify the management of the standard "Undo" and "Redo" menu entries, but it's not going to somehow synthesize a menu for you out of thin air, you have to set it first.